# Flink event time timer does not fire in testharness

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm trying to implement a tumbling window based calculation on event time characteristics with flink.

Therefore I have a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` doing all the work. With ProcessTimers everything works as expected in a unit test. Now I changed the code to work with Event Timers but the times do not trigger. (I do register the timers with registerEventTimeTimer)

Basically the test is like this

```java
  @Test
  public void evaluateFormular_ShouldSumOnTimer() throws Exception {
    long minutesToWait = 1;
    var definition = createTestCondition("Test", String.format("%s(_var)", method), "_var", "Test",
        "1", minutesToWait);

    var message = new CalculationControlMessage();
    message.setAction(ControlMessageAction.Create);
    message.setCalculationDefinition(definition);

    harness.processBroadcastElement(message, 100l);
    //harness.processBroadcastWatermark(5l);
    this.processValues(harness, values);
    // advance the watermark so that the timer can fire
    harness.processWatermark(Time.minutes(minutesToWait).toMilliseconds() + 1);

    assertEquals(harness.numEventTimeTimers(), 1);
    assertEquals("there should be a formular evaluated", 1, harness.extractOutputValues().size());
    harness.extractOutputValues().forEach(datapoint -> {
      assertEquals(datapoint.getValue(), expected, 0d);
    });
  }
```

For my understanding the watermark is manually advanced so that the timer can trigger. The watermark if definitely higher than the watermark from the event.

The harness is setup like this

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.KeyedBroadcastOperatorTestHarness;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.ProcessFunctionTestHarnesses;

public class FlinkHarness {
  public static KeyedBroadcastOperatorTestHarness<String, DataPointEvent, CalculationControlMessage, DataPointEvent> createForCalculations()
      throws Exception {
    var dynamicCalculationFunction = new DynamicCalculationFunction();
    
    var harness = ProcessFunctionTestHarnesses
        .forKeyedBroadcastProcessFunction(dynamicCalculationFunction, new KeySelector<>() {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1337L;

          @Override
          public String getKey(DataPointEvent value) throws Exception {
            return value.getDataPointKey();
          }

        }, Types.STRING, CalculationDescriptors.calculation);

    harness.setTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    harness.getExecutionConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(50l);
    harness.open();
    return harness;
  }
```

If I debug the function I can see that the timerService used by the test the `currentWatermark` is still at `-9223372036854775808`

I don't understand why the timer does not trigger. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it was unclear that on the testharness there are two methods to advance the watermark on an operator with multiple input streams.

> Yes, that makes sense. The overall watermark for an operator with multiple input channels is always the minimum of all incoming watermarks. So you must advance both watermarks

In that case with a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` within the test you always need to advance all incoming watermarks

So when calling `harness.processBroadcastElement(message, 0);` or `harness.processElement(new StreamRecord<DataPointEvent>(event, event.getTimestamp()));` both watermarks need to advanced with

```java
harness.processBroadcastWatermark(timestamp);
harness.processWatermark(timestamp);
```

Then the desired timer can fire

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared enough code to debug this, but I can point out a few things:

```java
this.processValues(harness, values);
```

Are these values StreamRecords that have timestamps assigned?

```java
harness.processWatermark(Time.minutes(minutesToWait).toMilliseconds() + 1);
```

Watermarks are absolute timestamps. This is going to be a very small watermark; not much larger than zero. Unless your timestamps start at zero this won't work.

```java
assertEquals(harness.numEventTimeTimers(), 1);
```

Sending through a watermark to trigger a timer should reduce the number of timers. Why isn't this zero?

Comment: in `processValues` i'm adding events which have all a timestamp starting from 0 for testability. I'm adding 10 datapoints with timestamps from 0...10. I'm adding them like

` harness.processElement(event, event.getTimestamp())` and advancing the watermark like `harness.processWatermark(new Watermark(event.getTimestamp()))` in `processValues`

The timer is created at timestamp: 60000 therefore I tried to advance to watermark to 60001

Comment: yes you are right `numEventTimeTimers` should be 0

Comment: I'm not sure if I am on the right track. But I discovered that there is this method on the harness `processBroadcastWatermark`. The process function has a broadcast stream and if I'm calling both methods `processBroadcastWatermark` and `processWatermark` the watermark is advanced and the timer is triggering

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The overall watermark for an operator with multiple input channels is always the minimum of all incoming watermarks. So you must advance both watermarks.